# JavaScript and svg basis

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a question, concerning JavaScript in combination with svg.
I am trying to animate the opacity in JavaScript. I know I can do it in CSS or with animation of svg BUT I want to learn JavaScript so I decided to do it. I am using setInterval and it is working fine if I am going down (from 1 to 0). The part "sphere.style.opacity = opacity - opac;" is working fine !!!! But if I change the MINUS TO PLUS the animation doesn't work. It doesn't go from 0 to 1!! I don't get it. This are basics and I don't get it. Of cource I change the value in the CSS. Anybody knows an answer?

HTML:

```
<svg height="99.7%" width="99.7%">
                <g id="sphere">
                    <circle id="circle" cx="500" cy="500" r="100" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2">
                    </circle>
                    <text id="text" x="500" y="515" font-size="50" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Verdana">JAVA</text>
                </g>
          </svg>
```

CSS:

```
#sphere{
opacity: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function animateOpacity(opac){
var sphere = document.getElementById("sphere");
var opacity = window.getComputedStyle(sphere).opacity;

sphere.style.opacity = opacity - opac;

//sphere.style.opacity = opacity + opac;

}

window.onload = function() { 
var opacity = 0.03;

function go() {
    animateOpacity(opacity);
}
setInterval(go, 100);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the opacity initially already at 1? So even if you keep adding, its always going to start at 1 and this is the max so makes sense no?

Comment: As i said in the description i put the value in the css on 0 if i am going plus... now on minus he is on 1

Comment: It doesnt make sense that minus works and plus not ...

Comment: Wild guess - it's treating `window.getComputedStyle(sphere).opacity` as a string, so when you do `+` it concatenates, whereas `-` implicitly converts it to a number.  Try `var opacity = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(sphere).opacity);`.  As I say, it's a guess, but you never know..

Comment: Tested it in jsfiddle, definitely a string

Comment: seems to be, if you use this: sphere.style.opacity = opacity*1 + opac*1 , it works

Comment: Its a String! It works when i parse it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computed opacity...

```
var opacity = window.getComputedStyle(sphere).opacity;
```

is returned as a string.

When reducing opacity...

```
sphere.style.opacity = opacity - opac;
```

the - operator converts the first argument from a string to a number and performs a subtraction (e.g. "1"-0.03 = 0.97, "0.97"-0.03 = 0.94, ...). The opacity is reduced as desired.

When increasing opacity...

```
sphere.style.opacity = opacity + opac;
```

the + operator converts the second argument from a number to a string and performs a string concatenation (e.g. "0"+0.03 = "00.03", "0.03"+0.03 = "0.030.03", ...). The opacity gets stuck at "0.03".

You can fix the problem by converting computed opacity to a number. For example...

```
var opacity = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(sphere).opacity);
```